# Change UILabel Text for a specific time period on a specific day

Tags: ios

First of all let me apologize for asking a question that is no doubt boring to 99% of the people that will see it. I have searched and come across different ideas but can't seem to get my head round implementing them.

Basically all I want to do is have a `UILabel` that says for example "This is a test" other than for 2 hours, between say 4 and 6pm on a Friday where it would say "this is not a test" and then from 6:01pm it would revert back to saying "This is a test" and would repeat every Friday.

I am using MarqueeLabel which is a subclass of `UILabel`, this is being done through Interface Builder and the below code in viewDidLoad.

```
self.scrollingLabel.marqueeType = MLContinuous;

self.scrollingLabel.scrollDuration = 40.0f;

self.scrollingLabel.fadeLength = 10.0f;

self.scrollingLabel.text = @"This is a test";

self.scrollingLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pauseTap:)];

tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[self.scrollingLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

self.scrollingLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

self.scrollingLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f,1.0f);

self.scrollingLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

self.scrollingLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5f;

self.scrollingLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;
```

Again apologies if this makes no sense but I am very new to **Xcode** and it is my first question on stack overflow.

Anything that points me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your existing code where you create the label

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
put this line to `viewDidLoad` method



And

-(void)targetMethod{
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE HH mm"];
 NSDate *dt = [NSDate date];
 NSString *dayAString = [formatter stringFromDate:dt];
 NSArray *array = [dayAString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
 if([[array objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Friday"] && [[array objectAtIndex:1] intValue]>=4 &&  [[array objectAtIndex:1] intValue]<=6 && [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue]>=0 && [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue]<=59)
       {
               self.scrollingLabel.text=@"this is not a test";
                 NSLog(@"On Air");
       }
       else{
               self.scrollingLabel.text=@"This is a test";
                  NSLog(@"Off Air");
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response however I'm getting a couple of errors... 1) No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'obejectAtIndex:' 2) Use of undeclared identifier 'string'

Comment: I Have managed to rectify the errors, however when run `self.scrollingLabel.text=@"this is not a test";` never gets called?

Comment: it will call when day=Friday and hour=4 to 6 and minute=0 to 59. set your system date frieday with time between 4 to 6

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have set the system time to 1559 however at 1600 it still doesn't get called.

Comment: can u put the string dayAsString value?

Comment: Still not being called, not sure what to do next??